# jquery to show invisible div

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a few questions as I am new to ASP.Net

1. I have an aspx page set up as follows;

   Unordered list area
   hidden div
   hidden div

The unordered list code:

```
<div class="literaltext">
        <p> We utilize two types of systems for mixing EnerBurn&reg; with your fuel supply to deliver it to your diesel engine,<br /> On-Board systems and Bulk Fueling systems. Click on an item below for more information.</p>
        <ul class="ulGreen">
            <li><b>On-Board systems - Road Vehicle</b><span style="color:black;"> (See an installation picture<a href="#" onclick="picDisplay('onBoardVehiclepicdisplay')">here</a>)</span> </li>
            <li><b>On-Board systems - Marine Vessel</b><span style="color:black;"> (See an installation picture<a href="#" onclick="picDisplay('onBoardVesselpicdisplay')">here</a>)</span> </li>
            <li><b>On-Board systems - Fueling Barge</b><span style="color:black;"> (See an installation picture<a href="#" onclick="picDisplay('onBoardBargepicdisplay')">here</a>)</span> </li>
            
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The hidden divs are set up like so;(only showing 2 of 3 for brevity)

```
<div id="onBoardVehiclepicdisplay" class="invisible">
        <fieldset class="dynamicinjectionpics">
            <legend>"Schlumberger On-Board Injection Unit"</legend>
             <img Height="300px" Width="400px" alt=""
             src="Images/InjectionUnitPictures/SchlumbergerInjectionUnit_FrackTruck.jpg"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <img Height="300px" Width="400px" alt=""
             src="Images/InjectionUnitPictures/SchlumbergerInjectionUnit_FrackTruck_withEnclosure.jpg"/>
             <br /><span id="Image1Text" runat="server">Typical injection unit installation (shown here on a Fracking Unit)</span>

        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div id="onBoardVesselpicdisplay" class="invisible">
        <fieldset class="dynamicinjectionpics">
            <legend>"Vessel Fuel Intake Line Mounted Injection System"</legend>
             <img Height="300px" Width="400px" alt=""
             src="Images/InjectionUnitPictures/SP-600 Injector.jpg"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <img Height="300px" Width="400px" alt=""
             src="Images/InjectionUnitPictures/MarionInjector Installation.JPG"/>
             <br /><span id="Span1" runat="server">Typical injection unit installation for single vessel</span>

        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

I want to use JQuery to change the class of the hidden divs to visible when they click on the anchor tag using the specified onclick function. Is this the best way to do this? Should I have an update panel around the hidden divs? The first method i used was to call a page reload where i injected the innerHTML for the selected tag's pictures, it works but I'm assuming that's an amateurish and less effective way of accomplishing this.

This query didn't work;(couldn't get the picDisplay function to recognize the parameter so I hard coded one of the div id's to try to get it to work)

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        function picDisplay(divId) {
            $("[id='onBoardVehiclepicdisplay']").toggleClass('visible');

        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: To select an element by its `id`, you can simply use a `#` followed by the `id` of the element as the selector. So instead of `$("[id='onBoardVehiclepicdisplay']")`, do `$("#onBoardVehiclepicdisplay")`.

Comment: JQuery has a built-in `toggle` function.

http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/toggle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I'd do:

Add a data-rel tag to each link, which refers to the relevant hidden div:

```
<a href="#" data-rel="onBoardVehiclepicdisplay">here</a>
```

Use the following jQuery:

```
$('.ulGreen').delegate('li a', 'click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).attr('data-rel');
    $('#' + target).toggleClass('invisible'); // or show()/hide()
});
```

EDIT - missed out the '#' from the toggleclass target. Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/aF5Pg/

Comment: As a side note, you can use $(this).data('rel') in this circumstance.

Comment: What's not working? is it the show/hide part? Do you have a demo we can see?

Comment: It works great in the fiddle but not on my aspx page. I even copied the html and jquery from the fiddle to ensure it was exactly the same.

Comment: Then something's out of whack on your ASP page; are you seeing any error messages in your browser's console that could help us narrow down the problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16950/discussion-between-dinotom-and-massivepenguin)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#onBoardVehiclepicdisplay').toggleClass('visible');
```

You should read this: [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).

You should also replace the onclick attribute (deprecated) with:

```
<li><a href="#onBoardVehiclepicdisplay">...</a>
```

```javascript
$('li > a').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //to block the link

    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    $(id).toggleClass('visible');
});
```

Comment: So i have to give the anchor tag an id? to reference the click function?

Comment: I don't sure to understand. To reference the click, use a selector to reference your html element (which has the onclick attribute now) like an id (#myId), a class (.myClass) or an element (a). jQuery selectors look like CSS selectors.

Comment: Edit : I didn't see your first code with the unordered list, i will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are two simple ways to do it :

1. Use .css()
2. Use .toggleClass() or .hasClass(), .removeClass() and .addClass()

I think the simplest on is by using .css()

You would have :

```
function toggleVisible() {
    if($(this).css("display") == "none")
        $(this).css("display", "block");
    else
        $(this).css("display", "none");
}
```

Comment: Too much complication. You can use .fadeToggle() function that achieves this.

Comment: .fadeToggle() will work with the opacity, and loops. Css display toggle will be less power-consuming.

Comment: There's no best way to do this, but several ones are correct. Your could use this too : http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: The best way of doing it is to add or remove classes, so in this situation the best would be .toggleClass().

Comment: I will try to say you that with the more respect possible : sometimes you are not absolutely right, your solution is not the badest, not the best too, because there is no BEST way to do it here. So please stop thinking you are the only one who's right because it is anti-constructive.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, you don't need an update panel to achieve what you're trying to do.
2. Secondly, we need a bit more information on your scenario to get the best result for you. Where are the buttons located, and is there going to be one button allocated to each  that you're trying to make visible?

i.e.

```
<div id="onBoardVesselpicdisplay">
</div>

<input id="onBoardButton" />
```

would be:

```
$('#onBoardButton').on('click', function() {
    $('#onBoardVesselpicdisplay').toggleClass('visible');
});
```

If your scenario is more complicated than that, then please explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: thedixon...there are no buttons, there is an anchor tag in the unordered list. When "here" is clicked i want JQuery to do the div class change

Comment: Oh, okay, well you can use the same code as above, as it's simply based on the element ids, whatever tag the element may be. So, the <input id="onBoardButton" /> would be your link with an ID, rather than a button.

Answer (score 0):

asp.net as I know will generate random client ID base on component id. so you can use [contain selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) on Jquery.

for your code, just modify to:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        function picDisplay(divId) {
            $("[id*='onBoardVehiclepicdisplay']").toggleClass('visible');

        }
    });

</script>
```

you can also manipulate using [end with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) or [start with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

[Here's another way of doing it](http://jsfiddle.net/5arx/FUaZR/15/). It makes use of the fact you can add multiple classes to HTML elements. First hide all the divs that are 'hideable' and onclick find the div you need to show and show it. I think a more modern way of doing it would be to use the `data-rel` attribute (but I'm at work and too busy to look it up - I haven't fully adopted it yet)

The divs are all hidden on load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Hide all of them initially
    $('.toHide').hide();
});
```

On a click of an anchor *inside* an LI the class name of the div to show is assembled and JQuery.show() is used to unhide it.

```
$('LI A').click(function() {
    $('.toHide').hide(); //hide all the divs first 
    $('.div-' +    ($(this).attr('class'))).show(); //reveal the one you want.
});
```

Comment: works great in the fiddle. There is no css for those two class names "toHide" and "div-001,2,3 etc" and when I refresh the page it shows all the divs without clicking on an anchor tag

Comment: The toHide divs are hidden by the JS code. You can use CSS to style them of course, but there's no need to use CSS directly to show/hide them as JQuery handles it all. If you're doing it on a page rather than in a fiddle you'll need in include the JQuery script and ensure you hide the toHide divs in the onload function